# How to move my edittext up when stkeyboard is on

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have created a login page. If I insert some text in edit text (username, password) etc then a softkeyboard is visible. but it comes on my password field view. So upper half of password field is visible while lower half is not because of that softkeyboard. I want when the softkeyboard is visible the password field to move up a little, so that the entire edittext will be visible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line in your `menifest.xml` file

```
<activity android:name=".your_activity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should shift up automatically when it has focus and the softkeyboard is displaying. I have a login form and I've done nothing special to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can solve this is by having a ScrollView as the root of your layout.